# Sending Azure Push Notifications Periodically

Tags: azure, push-notification, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I currently have an MVC / SQL application hosted in Azure that I would like to add push notification functionality to.

The scenario is that users register for alerts on the native mobile app (iOS / Android) and specify a latitude / longitude / radius per alert type. I'd like for each alert type to have a rules engine that evaluates on a schedule, determines the latest entries and then based on the user specified location and radius determines which users should now receive a corresponding notification.

I'm struggling to determine which Azure services should be used for this solution. I think that the Notification Hubs is the correct tool to use for sending the notifications. What I'm most unsure of is how to run the background processes on a schedule that wakes up, checks the latest entries, and selects which users to alert. I've came across WebJobs but these appear to be based on QueueInputs and monitoring storage items rather than running independent tasks?

Can someone give me some advice on the correct Azure services / SDKs that should be used to solve this scenario?

Thanks,
Brian.

Answer (score 2):

WebJobs can be triggered (e.g., QueueInputs),run on-demand, on schedule or continuously.

you can also use Azure Mobile Services as it has scheduling functionality and plugs-in well with Notifications as well.

Comment: So I can create a web job, poll a database and determine information, then send calls to my notification hub? And set the scheduling up as a run-on-demand or scheduled task without any queue elements?

Comment: you use the queue elements if you want that to trigger your job. you can even run plain console apps or scripts in WebJobs